# Problema com depuração

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

Estou a desenvolver um projeto que possui um sistema de logon completo com `Roles`, `User` e `Goups`, porém quando renomeei o projeto pede para Anexar a Processo ao invés de DEPURAR, como resolver isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quais foram os procedimentos usados para renomear seu projeto? Ao que tudo indica, alguma coisa foi feita errada e o Visual Studio não reconhece mais seu projeto como um projeto MVC.

Comment: segui este tutorial [link](http://typecastexception.com/post/2013/12/15/Visual-Studio%E2%80%93Painlessly-Renaming-Your-Project-and-Solution-Directories.aspx)

Comment: Se possível poste o conteúdo do csproj pra a gente dar uma olhada.

Answer (score 1):

- Faça um `Unload Project` no seu projeto (botão direito nele > <kbd>Unload Project</kbd>);
- Edite o `.csproj` (botão direito novamente no projeto > <kbd>Edit NovoNome.csproj</kbd>);
- Confira se a seguinte tag está idêntica ao conteúdo abaixo:

  ```
  <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
  ```
- Salve o `.csproj` e faça um Reload (botão direito no projeto > <kbd>Reload Project</kbd>).